# Sharing state between two components in different files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react file that has the next useState:

```
 const [isEmpty, setIsEmpty] = useState(false);
```

in this file I have the next useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //when the state of isEmpty is changed, do something
}, isEmpty);
```

I have a second react file that I would like also to have the same useEffect code, so I could do some stuff if the state of isEmpty is changed on the first file.

How can I so that?

I tried to export the useState but I get an error.
is there an easy way to share state between 2 react files?
can someone give share an example?

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components

Comment: add a param to the nextjs component of `isEmpty` and `setIsEmpty` in your useEffect file.

Answer (score -1):

not sure what exacly do you want to achieve, but i guess you can "lift your parent state up" or just use Context/state managment, depends on what you needs. here's example how you can use your state in other "react files"/components.

```
export const ExampleParent = () => {
  const [isEmpty, setIsEmpty] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('do your thing with isEmpty state', isEmpty);
  }, [isEmpty]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIsEmpty((isEmpty) => !isEmpty)}>toggle isEmpty </button>
      <ExampleChildOne isEmpty={isEmpty} />
      <ExampleChildTwo isEmpty={isEmpty} />
    </>
  );
};

function ExampleChildOne({ isEmpty }: { isEmpty: boolean }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {isEmpty && 'i am empty'}
      <p>{`Empty prop is ${isEmpty}`} </p>
    </div>
  );
}

function ExampleChildTwo({ isEmpty }: { isEmpty: boolean }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {!isEmpty && 'i am not empty'}
      <p>{`Empty prop is ${isEmpty}`} </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

ofc in this example you can just export your two child components.

So on short =>  your 2 react files should depend on same  state

https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext reference for context.